# rearrange select optgroup tag based on attribute value jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, sorting

My html code coming dynamically like as follows. But i want to do sorting based on attribute "datagroupid".

```
<select id="parts" multiple="multiple" class="parameterdropdown">
<optgroup value="9" label="B3_L1" datagroupid="9">
      <option value="12">A01_Process1_Sub1</option>
      <option value="14">A03_Process3_Sub1 </option>
 </optgroup>
<optgroup value="6" label="A2_L2" datagroupid="6">
      <option value="7">A01_Process1_Sub1</option>
      <option value="9">A03_Process3_Sub1 </option>
</optgroup>
 <optgroup value="3" label="A1_L1" datagroupid="3">
      <option value="3">A01_Process1_Sub1</option>
      <option value="4">A03_Process3_Sub1 </option>
</optgroup>
</select>
```

I tried the following script. It is not working. Please help me.

```
$("#parts").html($("#parts optgroup").sort(function (a, b) {
     return a.text == b.text ? 0 : a.label < b.label ? -1 : 1  ;
}));
```

Expecting output like as follows.

```
<select id="parts" multiple="multiple" class="parameterdropdown">
 <optgroup value="3" label="A1_L1" datagroupid="3">
      <option value="3">A01_Process1_Sub1</option>
      <option value="4">A03_Process3_Sub1 </option>
</optgroup>
<optgroup value="6" label="A2_L2" datagroupid="6">
      <option value="7">A01_Process1_Sub1</option>
      <option value="9">A03_Process3_Sub1 </option>
</optgroup>
<optgroup value="9" label="B3_L1" datagroupid="9">
      <option value="12">A01_Process1_Sub1</option>
      <option value="14">A03_Process3_Sub1 </option>
 </optgroup>
</select>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to change your code to this: https://codepen.io/creativedev/pen/QxmaOG

```
$("#parts").html($("#parts optgroup").sort(function (a, b) {
     return $(a).attr('datagroupid') == $(b).attr('datagroupid') ? 0 : a.label < b.label ? -1 : 1  ;
}));
```

Answer (score 1):

Since the arguments to the `sort` function are native DOM elements, not jQuery objects, you have to use standard JS methods if you aren't going to convert them to jQuery objects first:

```js
$("#parts").html($("#parts optgroup").sort(
  (a, b) => a.textContent === b.textContent || b.label < a.label
));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="parts" multiple="multiple" class="parameterdropdown">
<optgroup value="9" label="B3_L1" datagroupid="9">
      <option value="12">A01_Process1_Sub1</option>
      <option value="14">A03_Process3_Sub1 </option>
 </optgroup>
<optgroup value="6" label="A2_L2" datagroupid="6">
      <option value="7">A01_Process1_Sub1</option>
      <option value="9">A03_Process3_Sub1 </option>
</optgroup>
 <optgroup value="3" label="A1_L1" datagroupid="3">
      <option value="3">A01_Process1_Sub1</option>
      <option value="4">A03_Process3_Sub1 </option>
</optgroup>
</select>
```

Comment: Thanks For your Quick Reply. It is working fine. Sorry due to low reputation am not able to give vote to your answer.

Comment: You have 19 reputation, pretty sure that's enough? :)

Answer (score 1):

You can try the following:

```js
$("#parts").html($("#parts optgroup").sort(function (a, b) {
   a = a.label;
   b = b.label; 
   return (a < b) ? -1 : (a > b) ? 1 : 0;
}));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="parts" multiple="multiple" class="parameterdropdown">
<optgroup value="9" label="B3_L1" datagroupid="9">
      <option value="12">A01_Process1_Sub1</option>
      <option value="14">A03_Process3_Sub1 </option>
 </optgroup>
<optgroup value="6" label="A2_L2" datagroupid="6">
      <option value="7">A01_Process1_Sub1</option>
      <option value="9">A03_Process3_Sub1 </option>
</optgroup>
 <optgroup value="3" label="A1_L1" datagroupid="3">
      <option value="3">A01_Process1_Sub1</option>
      <option value="4">A03_Process3_Sub1 </option>
</optgroup>
</select>
```